# PYTHON return 2 csv files endpoint FLASK RESTX

Tags: python, rest, csv, response

I have an endpoint that calculates some statistics, and wants to return 2 csv files. Something like "stats_people.csv" "stats_calculation.csv".

I am at point that I have 2 dataframes,

```
    df_stats_ppl = pd.DataFrame(people, columns=ppl_column_names)
    df_stats_calculation = pd.DataFrame(calculation, columns=calculation_column_names)
```

and I tried stuff like this:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('output.zip', 'w') as csv_zip:
        csv_zip.writestr("stats_ppl.csv", df_stats_ppl.to_csv())
        csv_zip.writestr("stats_calculation.csv", df_stats_calculation.to_csv())

        response = send_file(
            outputfile,
            as_attachment=True,
            attachment_filename='output.zip',
            # cache_timeout=0
        )

        return response
```

but this makes zip and additional files in the root directory (and also for some reason the zip file is empty, thats why I just put `outputfile` placeholder to the function because I was probably wrong with what should be written there).

But I want to have many requests to this endpoint, potentially at the same time, and I worry someone else will get data they were not supposed to if the files are going to get created and stored somewhere.

Is there a way I could create a zip with 2 csv files WITHOUT saving?

Is there a better way than send a zip? I dont know how to send 2 files a different way.

Thanks a lot!